# Is there a way to disable a transaction column via Scripting with Netsuite 2.0?

Tags: javascript, netsuite, sublist, suitescript2.0

I am required to write some code that disables a transaction column e.g. 'quantity' on a sublist e.g. 'item' on say a purchase order.

I seem to have reached a block as my code is not working.

See my code below:

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.0
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
define(['N/record'],
/**
 * @param {record} record
 */
function(record) {
     function sublistChanged(scriptContext) {
        var currentForm = scriptContext.currentRecord;

        var getSublist = currentForm.getSublist({
            sublistId: 'item'
            fieldId: 'quantity'
                });
       getSublist.isDisabled = true;
        }

    return {     
        sublistChanged: sublistChanged,

    };

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not use the `isDisabled` property to change field display. The proper way to modify field display types in NetSuite is to retrieve a reference to the `Field` object, then call its `updateDisplayType()` method. See the Help page titled `Field.updateDisplayType(options)` for details on this method.

To retrieve a reference to a sublist column, you:

1. Retrieve a reference to the `Sublist` from the `Form` or `Record`
2. Retrieve a reference to the `Field` from the `Sublist`
3. Invoke `updateDisplayType()` on the `Field`

Will end up looking something like:

```
var sublist = context.newRecord.getSublist(...);
var column = sublist.getField(...);
column.updateDisplayType(...);
```

Comment: Thanks erictgrubaugh for coming back so quickly.  

Having reviewed the Field.updateDisplayType(options) on 'help', it appears to that it can only be used on the sever side for a suitelet.

The aim is to allow the user interact with a native NS form/page e.g by ticking a checkbox, disable a sublist field/column.

Apologies if I have missed something rather obvious or previously mentioned.

Thanks for you anticipated help.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you cannot disable a sublist field in client script(As per [NetSuite](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4794215939.html&whence=), `isDisabled` is read-only). You can only update sublist-field display type for sublist which were created using **N/ui** module.